# Swap axis of a quaternion?

Tags: c#, quaternions

I have some quaternion rotation data that i am using in C#. I need to add functionality to adjust the resulting rotation, so that I can (for example) switch axis Y with axis Z, or invert the X value.
If the quaternion is:

```
qX 0.70711
qY 0
qZ 0.70711
qW 0
```

The resulting rotation in EulerXYZ degrees is:

```
X 0
Y 90
Z 0
```

If I need my result to be:

```
X 0
Y 0
Z 90
```

What do I have to do to the quaternion to achieve this result? Is it as simple as changing the values from qY and qZ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't describe 3d mirroring with quaternions.

Comment: Damn. So there is no way to do this without converting to euler? Is it possible to swap the axes?

Comment: Its never possible to describe a 3d mirroring as a composition of rotations. Doesn't matter which one you use: a single quaternion or euler coordinates.

Comment: I think what you want is not a mirroring transformation, but another rotation which is derived from the original rotations euler coordinates

Comment: Well, I am not aware of a method to express it as quaternion multiplication. I am almost sure that swapping qy and qz is not sufficient

Comment: If it was Eulers, I would simply change `(X,Y,Z)`for `(X,Z,Y)`, or `(X,Y,Z)` for `(-X,Y,Z)`. That is what I am trying to achieve, using quats.

Comment: The latter is just negating qx, the former is not that simple in my opinion

Comment: Ok, so to negate an axis, i can just negate the `qx`, `qy`, or `qz`, as I would usually in my non-quaternion world? To switch axes, could I perhaps multiply by another quaternion?

Comment: Well, at first I thought it will only work with the first axis, but now I think this method works neither.